# Join or group table to remove repetitions in one column only

Tags: mysql, sorting, join, group-by

I'm trying to sort out this puzzle for more than few hours now, the table is as below:

```
table:
n1  n2  r
---------
A   D   G
B   D   G
C   D   G
A   E   G
B   E   G
C   E   G
A   F   G
B   F   G
C   F   G
```

And results expected:

```
result:
n1  n2  r
---------
A   D   G   
B   E   G
C   F   G
```

I was trying grouping, joining, but no lack. Here is the code, but it gives me completely different results:

```
select * from table t1
    join table t2
    on t2.r = t1.r
    and t1.n1 > t2.n1
```

In general n1 and n2 should be grouped by r and repetitions in n2 should be removed.

Comment: it appears you want the the distinct values of n1 and n2 sorted ascending and then paired together.  but that's a guess... what's the rules governing how n1 and n2 relate?

Comment: can you describe the actual assignment? What are the rules that determine the correct result?

Comment: Without the stipulations on the puzzle, there are too many possibilities, some ridiculously direct like `WHERE (n1, n2, r) IN (('A','D','G'),('B','E','G'),('C','F','G'))`; and there is probably also a complicated recursive one.

Comment: Thanks guys for getting back, the table is much bigger, this is just the snipped. Unfortunately, simple WHERE IN, would not work here.

Comment: @xQbert, n1 and n1 have to be paired and r is always the same, I mean n1 and n2 should be grouped by r.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DEMO on Rextester](http://rextester.com/TXR52461)

The following uses user variables to simulate a row number analytic to assign a row number to each unique value in columns n1 and n2.  This value in addition to `R` is used to join the two sets Der_N1 and Der_N2 so that we can generate a result set paring each value in N1 to each value in N2 ensuring each value is used only once for each value of `R.`

```
SELECT N1, N2, Der_N1.R
FROM (SELECT Distinct N1, R, @N1RN:=@N1RN+1 RN 
      FROM (SELECT distinct N1, R 
            FROM SO48873185) X 
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT @N1RN:=0) Z) Der_N1
INNER JOIN (SELECT Distinct N2, R, @N2RN:=@N2RN+1 RN 
            FROM (SELECT distinct N2, R 
                   FROM SO48873185) X 
                   CROSS JOIN (SELECT @N2RN:=0) Z) Der_N2
 on Der_N1.RN = Der_N2.RN
and Der_N1.R = Der_N2.R
```

Resulting in:

```
+----+----+----+---+
|    | N1 | N2 | R |
+----+----+----+---+
|  1 | A  | D  | G |
|  2 | B  | E  | G |
|  3 | C  | F  | G |
+----+----+----+---+
```

Assumption being the lowest value N1 (x) should be paired with the lowest value N2 (y) and the next lowest x(x+1) should be paired with the next lowest N2(y+1) in ascending order and so on..

By including R on the join; I believe we handle each set and no grouping is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with them; and not sure which version MySQL actually introduced them, but I believe you'll need a recursive "CTE" (common table expression). Something like:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte (n1, n2, r) AS
(
  SELECT n1, n2, r FROM theTable ORDER BY n1, n2 ASC LIMIT 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT n1, n2, r 
  FROM theTable AS t
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
       SELECT 1 
       FROM cte AS c 
       WHERE c.n1 IN (t.n1, t.n2) OR c.n2 IN (t.n1, t.n2)
       )
  ORDER BY n1, n2 ASC 
  LIMIT 1
)
SELECT * FROM cte;
```

*You might need to mess with the LIMIT on that second part; if it works without modification I'd actually be a a little surprised.*